# Scripts Not Working on MVC Generated Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on a complex web page which will highlight areas on a map using ASP.Net 6 MVC.  This required a lot of scripting but was not working. I then found that the script was not being triggered at all.  To see if I could figure out what was going on I created a very basic page with a very basic _layout behind it using $(document).ready and alert() to see if the script was being called, and it wasn't. I've got way more sophisticated web pages with a scripting element and they work fine.  Any ideas where the problem might lie?

The very basic _layout I'm using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

The bare bones web page which is called via a controller, produces the word 'test' but does not appear to trigger the document ready:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Nothing.cshtml";
}
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("ready")
         }
    </script>
 }
```

Comment: What is the resulting client-side page produced by this?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?

Comment: Where have you included jQuery?

Comment: Thanks, guys. You were quite right about the missing jQuery, which I then added, still nothing.  Couldn't see any error in the console.  But I've now reverted to an earlier copy of the project and found that scripts seem to be running ok in that, so I'll try again with what I was working on.